# Unable to pass the root MySQL password into an AWS ECS Fargate launch type WordPress deployment

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker-compose, aws-fargate

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the root MySQL password into an ECS Fargate luanch type WordPress deployment. I'm working with [this official AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html) which provides this sample docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options: 
        awslogs-group: tutorial
        awslogs-region: us-east-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: wordpress
```

Note how there's no second "mysql" service defined (the way it would be for the [EC2 launch type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-ec2.html)). This approach does work; I get the "Welcome to WordPress" page, but then I'm asked "Before getting started, we need some information on the database" - which means that WordPress has no idea how to connect to the database. On a regular Docker deployment, I'd SSH into the container and manually set up a DB password etc. But that's not possible on Fargate.
I've tried adding environment values to the docker-compose.yml file using variations of this:

```
environment:
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$wpadmin'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$wpdb'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$secret'
```

and this:

```
environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

And, of course, I've tried exporting it to my host env and referencing it in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
```

But nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the wordpress application running on PID 1?

Comment: ecs-cli ps shows the WordPress container is up. But I can't imagine I would have seen the "Welcome to WordPress" page if it wasn't running.